Local Storage Form Array Overwritten After Refresh
I'm working to store input data from a Squarespace form to local storage. The objective is to persist all form fields locally, until the form is submitted. This way, users don't lose any data if they accidentally close the tab or navigate to a different page. I have applied the following code to my specific application. The form includes four input types (Text, Email, Text Area, and Checkbox). For alignment, I set a custom attribute name to each input. Lastly, I added the window.onload function to execute the script after the form has loaded.
While in session, I'm able to add values to the Form array in localStorage and update or edit as expected. However, if inputs are stored in a session and the page is refreshed, any subsequent addition or edit of an input results in all previous values being deleted. I suspect there is a minor omission in the code when handling the array key, a configuration error with setItem and getItem, or nuance related to the React structure. I have attempted the following solution and I'm unable to find any working examples to persist a Squarespace form.
Code: Local Storage
$(window).on('load', function () {

Name = document.getElementById('text-cc23c8ea-6327-4428-a14a-b3fb48c68303-field');
Email = document.getElementById('email-yui_3_17_2_1_1676942394006_15077-field');
Phone = document.getElementById('text-98fe5141-07c9-45c7-a3cf-3055be1b1f1c-field');
Company = document.getElementById('text-f5c0d7f9-0fb2-4533-95c0-11d9a232c96a-field');
Website = document.getElementById('text-040063da-dff1-41a6-8471-3e4cb7ebfd44-field');
Background = document.getElementById('textarea-73d1c76d-d63e-4f84-abad-de04a711eee5-field');
Requirements = document.getElementById('textarea-ed868b91-765d-4c42-9fc6-5943d50237b5-field');
Description = document.getElementById('textarea-ed868b91-765d-4c42-9fc6-5943d50237b5-field');
Service = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section[data-section-id="63f41c32be07cb3324ff12cf"] .react-form-contents input, section[data-section-id="63f41c32be07cb3324ff12cf"] .react-form-contents textarea'));
elems.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('input', handleChange, false));

let cached = getForm();
if(cached) {
Name.value = cached.Name;
Email.value = cached.Email;
Phone.value = cached.Phone;
Company.value = cached.Company;
Website.value = cached.Website;
Background.value = cached.Background;
Requirements.value = cached.Requirements;
Description.value = cached.Description;

if(cached.Service) {
Service.forEach(c => {
if(cached.Service.includes(c.value)) c.checked = true;});
}}

document.querySelector('section[data-section-id="63f41c32be07cb3324ff12cf"] .react-form-contents').addEventListener('submit', () => {
window.localStorage.removeItem('Form');}, false);

function handleChange(e) {

console.log('Form Update');
let Form = {};
Form.Name = Name.value;
Form.Email = Email.value;
Form.Phone = Phone.value;
Form.Company = Company.value;
Form.Website = Website.value;
Form.Background = Background.value;
Form.Requirements = Requirements.value;
Form.Description = Description.value;

Form.Service = [];
Service.forEach(c => {
if(c.checked) Form.Service.push(c.value);
});

saveForm(Form);}

function saveForm(Form) {
let f = JSON.stringify(Form);
window.localStorage.setItem('Form', f);}

function getForm() {
let f = window.localStorage.getItem('Form');
if(f) return JSON.parse(f);}

});


While I appreciate the effort you've put so far into posting this question... your question code is a good bit different than your codepen code and you mention React in the question (and in the css class you're selecting on!) but not only is none of your code React it won't work at all with React. You're problem is quite possibly that imperative DOM manipulations generally won't work with React. If you're not using React, please remove mention of it from the question.

If you navigate to the link in the original post and inspect the code, you will notice that Squarespace utilizes React for the Form Block which I am attempting to persist.

In that case, you would need to modify the React form code itself. if that code is the vendor's and you don't have access you will not be able to do this. File a feature request ticket with them. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(

This was more of a learning exercise to see if I could make it work and offer the solution to others. At this point, I'm about 95 percent of the way there. When you input fields into the form during the initial session, everything is stored accordingly upon refresh. It's only when you start editing the form in the next session do the previous values get deleted.

...except that there's no guarantee that behavior will be consistent across different versions of React, or at all really. React owns the DOM tree it renders. What you are attempting to do is a fragile hack that explicitly violates the API contract and they can and will break you in 1000 different ways. If you can get this to work (and that's a big if) there's no guarantee it will stay working.

Comfort wants you dead. I'm in the process of migrating from Squarespace due to lack of control and innovation. Started building out a platform with Next.js so I don't have to spend time injecting code to provide a dynamic, user-friendly experience. In this case, it seems like I would need to adjust the useState or useEffect but not totally sure.

In React (incl nextjs) you would keep the validated form state in React state and you could do the persistence serialization on valid user inputs along with updating the React state in the onChange listener. And again, best of luck I'm sorry I didn't have a better fix for you.

No worries, Jared. I appreciate the response and willingness to assist. Trying to figure out if it's possible to inject React code using the <script> tag  to manipulate the form state. The built-in code block within Squarespace only supports JavaScript, Markdown, HTML, CSS, and Plain Text.
